# Oracle PL/SQL package/procedure for processing CSV from CLOB

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

I am allowing a user to upload a .csv file via OHS/mod_plsql.  This file gets saved as a BLOB file in the database, which I then convert to CLOB.  I want to then take the contents of this CLOB file and save its contents into a table.  I already have some working code that splits the file based on line endings, then splits each resulting string along commas and inserts the records.

What I need is a way to handle the case where a string within the CSV is enclosed in double-quotes and contains a comma.  For example:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
some,text,more,text
this,text,has,"commas, semicolons, and periods"
```

My code will know how to process the second line, but not the third.  Does anyone have some code that is smart enough to treat "commas, semicolons, and periods" as a single token?  I could probably hack something together, but I don't trust my regular expression skills enough, and I figure someone else has probably already written something that does this same thing that would be willing to share.

Comment: Would code that parses double-quote-delimited strings also need to handle escaped double-quotes that are part of the cell contents? I'm wondering if it might be easier to write the file to disk with `UTL_FILE`, load it as an external table, and then delete the file. Seems odd to use the filesystem like that though.

Comment: A quick search threw up [this](https://slobaexpert.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/loading-csv-files-into-oracle-tables-using-plsql/), which might give you some ideas.

Comment: I can probably use that example.  I'm not positive yet of the format of the CSV we'll be receiving, but I'll just have to stipulate that they cannot have double-quotes within their files except those that are used when delimiting strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good CSV parser in the Alexandria PL/SQL Library - CSV_UTIL_PKG.

https://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/

More info:

http://ora-00001.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/select-from-spreadsheet-or-how-to-parse.html

Comment: Holy cow, how have I never seen that page before?  That has all sorts of libraries I could use.  Thanks!